# str_extract_all returns a list but I want a vector

Tags: r, stringr

Still relatively new to R here. I have a column of tweets, and I'm trying to create a column that contains the retweet handle "RT @blahblah", like this:

```
Tweets                            Retweetfrom
RT @john I had a good day         RT @john
RT @josh I had a bad day          RT @josh
```

This is my code:

```
r$Retweetfrom <- str_extract_all(r$Tweets, "^RT[:space:]+@[:graph:]+")
```

It's giving me the result alright, but instead of a vector, the new column is a list. When I try to unlist it, it throws me an error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Retweetfrom", value = c("@AlpineITW", "@AllScienceGlobe",  : replacement has 1168 rows, data has 2306
```

Anyone know how to deal with this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there's just one RT @user in each of row of the `Tweets` column (not a very strong assumption) then you may only want `str_extract` (which will vectorise over the strings) not `str_extract_all` (which may return multiple results per row). i.e.

```
r$Retweetfrom <- str_extract(r$Tweets, "^RT[:space:]+@[:graph:]+")
```

in which case you will get the first mention of RT @user, which is probably the one you want anyway.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense thank you! But what if I'm trying to extract all the mentions in the tweets? Sometimes there are more than one mentions in one tweet.

Comment: That is a slightly different question; your regex at the moment captures the person who RT'd given that (and I missed it first time around) you use `^` in the regex, so you will only get one at most (my bad again, missed the `+`; you'll get them all). If you wanted to capture all of the `@user` mentions in a tweet, whether or not they did the RT, then you would need to decide on how you want to store a variable-size list in a `data.frame`.

Comment: That makes so much more sense now. Thank you very much Jonathan!

Comment: Pretty sure you can just do 'simplify = T' and it will turn the results into a variable size matrix.

Answer (score 3):

If we are interested in a `base R` option, `sub` will be useful

```
r$Retweetfrom <- sub(".*\\b(RT\\s+@[[:graph:]]+)\\s+.*", 
                         "\\1", r$Tweets)
r$Retweetfrom
#[1] "RT @john" "RT @josh"
```